# Issue with managing the download of .dat file with Mozilla

Tags: firefox, javascript, html5, cross-browser

I will try to format my question as much as I can. Apologies if It is unclear.

Background : Mozilla corrupts the .dat file while downloaded using window.open method from the application. It opens up with junk chracters while opened using Notepad. This works fine on other browsers such as IE and CHROME.

While troubleshooting I observed, the size of abc.dat while downloaded using mozilla was 3 to 4 times less compared other browsers.

I understand, we can specify the mapping of file extensions and actions to be taken while download in profile in mozilla, but could not make much progress on it. I do see there is only on default profile and could not figure out if there is anything to do on default profile's extensions.cache, extensions.json and extensions.ini file.

So my Question is - How do i handle the mapping of .dat extension with Mozilla. It is pretty obvious that Mozilla does not handle the .dat extensions well. Is there a way I can configure my mozilla browser to act correctly while downloading .dat files?

P.S I have tried resetting the browser but it did not help.

Thanks,

Comment: It might be beneficial to list your FF version.

Comment: You might try resetting *handlers.json* in your profile, or adding a new handler for .DAT files. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/applications-panel-set-how-firefox-handles-files